# Convert array of objects to array of values in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have below code in my laravel application controller:

```
$levels =  $request->level;
return $levels;
```

and it returns like this:

```
{
  1: [
    "9226"
  ],
  2: [
    "166"
  ]
}
```

which I need is return just values (9226,166) as array like below:

```
{
  "9226",
  "166"
}
```

How to get just values?

Comment: you can use `flatten` method of laravel directly `$levels->flatten();` it will solve your problem

Comment: @SalmanZafar According to the title, It is an array, not a collection. `$request->level` also suggests it is not a collection.

Comment: You can first convert it into collection by using collect method and then you can easily convert it into `flatten` array using laravel builtin method `$levels = collect($request->level);` `return $levels->flatten();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if array then you can use `array_flatten()`

```
array_flatten($levels)
```

if it is collection then

```
$ar = $levels->flatten();
$ar->all();  // get array
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_values` function to get the values from the array. As your function is returning an a object so you need to convert that to array and then use the `array_values`

Ex.

```
$levels = array_values((array)$levels);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Laravel's Collection. For example:

```
$level = [1 => ["9226"], 2 => ["166"]]; // or $request->level;

dd(
    array_flatten($level),
    collect($level)->flatten()->toArray()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_merge(...$levels);`

You can use array_merge to flatten 2D arrays as of PHP 5.6 with the use of the splat operator (`...`).

** edit:

```
{
  1: [
    "9226"
  ],
  2: [
    "166"
  ]
}
```

Is an object, which as Ashok Gadri has mentioned, which you will need to convert to an array before using array syntax.